# Copying multiple sources to single destination

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB.net and am trying to create a backup utility to copy a set of local folders to a single backup destination (on usb for example) with a progress bar. After googling for the last few hours I can only find examples of single folder to single destination.

Can anyone point me in the direction of an example?

UPDATE:

Based of @Werdna example, I have created a simple FOR EACH NEXT loop. However the next issue is that only the files within the source directories are being copied to the target directory, rather than the folders and all their contents. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Start_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Start.Click

    Dim destination = "E:\Backup Folder"

    Dim sources As New List(Of String)

    sources.Add("D:\Profiles\Users\Desktop")
    sources.Add("D:\Profiles\Users\Mail")
    sources.Add("D:\Profiles\Users\Downloads")

    For Each source As String In sources
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(source, destination)
    Next
    MessageBox.Show("Copy Completed")
End Sub
End Class
```

Also, what is the best method to use the FOR EACH NEXT loop to count the number of files to be copied? I would like to output the amount to a label as well as use it for a progressbar as the utility evolves.

Comment: `single folder to single` so what do you want instead?

Comment: also use background worker, comes with progress bar and any GUI you will use wont freeze during copying process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is something that i have quickly written up for you to give you some idea on how i went about completing your task. You will need to add 2 listboxes to your application, a folder open dialog and a few buttons, this might not be what you are looking for, unfortunately you cant select multiable folders with the other dialogs, however nevertheless, take a look below, the code isn't completely as there is always something to do, however this should lead you in the right direction hopefully!

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each item In IO.Directory.GetDirectories("C:\")
        ListBox1.Items.Add(item)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each item In ListBox1.SelectedItems
        ListBox2.Items.Add(item & "\")
    Next
    ListBox1.SelectedItem = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    ListBox2.Items.Remove(ListBox2.SelectedItem)
    ListBox2.SelectedItem = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    For Each item In IO.Directory.GetDirectories(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        ListBox1.Items.Add(item)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)
        For Each item In ListBox2.Items
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(item, FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)
        Next
        MessageBox.Show("Copy Completed.")
    End If
End Sub
```

`End Class`

I wrote this in about 10 minutes, so i didnt get a change to do a progessbar, however if this is what you are looking for, then i am happy to help you add one to your program. Happy Coding!

UPDATE - BASED OFF YOUR NEW QUESTION

```
Public Class Form1

Dim NumberofFILEs As Integer = 0

Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    Dim Location1 = "C:\Backup Folder\TESTING\FOLDER"
    Dim source As String = "C:\TESTING\FOLDER"

    Dim source1 As String = "C:\TESTING1\FOLDER"
    Dim Location2 = "C:\Backup Folder\TESTING1\FOLDER"

    IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\Backup Folder\TESTING\FOLDER")
    IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\Backup Folder\TESTING1\FOLDER")


    For Each item In source
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(source, Location1, True)
    Next


    For Each item In source1
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(source1, Location2, True)
    Next
    MessageBox.Show("Completed")

    For Each file In source1.Count & source.Count
        NumberofFILEs += 1
    Next
    Label1.Text = NumberofFILEs
End Sub
```

End Class

Edit the locations and destinations to what you need. Also the True at the end of the copydirectory means that it will overwrite any files with the same name, eg it will update them pretty much

Comment: Thanks for that @Werdna! Is there a way to do this without the Listboxes? As in preset the sources and destination in a string?

Comment: @Adam you want to basically click add and how them go to some sort of list? you could do this i believe, however you would have to add each folder 1 by 1
eg - have an openfilediaglog select the file and add them to a listbox and then later save them to the destination.

Comment: thanks again! With your example I have learned to create a basic loop. I have updated my answer if you could be of any more help.

Comment: OK i have updated my answer based on your question, to add more items follow the pattern. @Adam

Comment: you're updated example was just what I needed. Based of it i have the core of my app done and working. I have marked your answer as the solution. Thanks you again!

Comment: @Adam No problem at all, happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can copy each folder to the destination, one at a time. Loop through the source folders and copy each one to the target folder.

Comment: Would you happen to have a code snippet or example? I would love to see the syntax.